# How to load php_pdo_sqlsrv_54.dll?

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp

I'm using WAMP 2.2 (PHP 5.4.3) on Windows 7 64bit and I like to use PHP to connect to MS SQL Server 2005 Express Edition.

I downloaded [Microsoft Drivers 3.0 for PHP for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) and unzip the file php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll to the php's extension directory.

I appended php.ini with additional "extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll".

After restarting WAMP, I got an error message dialog.
[image: Error Dialog]

How to fix it?

One more thing, why php keep putting pdo_mssql on it's php.ini, is it available anyway?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You use 64-bit while the DLL library you try to use is 32-bit. Read somewhere that WAMP, XAMPP and so on doesn't like that. Try to find a 64-bit version of that DLL.